# Is it okay to rely on CocoaPods when deploying an app?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, developer-program

Can I deploy my app to AppStore with 5-10 cocoapods? All pods have MIT licence.

Comment: To be on topic, this should really about what Apple allows for its service and be less about the programming implications. I could see one version of this here to address the policy / Apple involvement and another question likely on stack overflow about the wisdom of this from a craft / code health standpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add as many cocoapods to your app as required, it makes no difference regarding the count of packages.

Many of the most popular apps have a dozen or more packages.  However, whether or not you should be using that many packages is an entirely different question.

Also, your point about the MIT license is a good one.  You should also be acknowledging all these package creators within your app somewhere.  For example, in my app's Settings page I have a tableview row that lists the packages my app uses.  App Store review will not check for that but it I think it's required with the MIT license.